# How to get Input value and show it on a button click in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to `react js` and I am trying to **get input value and set it to another `html` element (p)**

And other thing is, I find it really hard to leran `react js` with all these complex syntaxes and things related to `react js`, are there any good tutorials that I can understand?

This is what I have been trying by researching all over the internet and I cannot go beyond this simple thing... Using `jquery` i could have done this so easily, and `react js` seems so complex to get the job done for some reason (maybe I am wrong). Anyway,

This is my `SelectTrainsAndTickets.jsx`

```
"use strict";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

class SelectTrainsAndTickets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        noOfTickets: {document.getElementById('tickets')} //getting user input value
    };
  }

  showDetails() {
    this.setState({
        noOfTickets: 
    });
    console.log(this.state.noOfTickets);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2" />
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <select id="train" name="train" className="form-control">
                <option value="select" disabled="disabled">
                  - Select Train -
                </option>
                <option value="1">Train A</option>
                <option value="2">Train B</option>
                <option value="3">Train C</option>
                <option value="4">Train D</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <input id="tickets"
                className="form-control"
                type="number"
                placeholder="Number of tickets"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-2" />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2" />
            <div className="col-md-4" />
            <div className="col-md-4 text-right">
              <button
                onClick={this.showDetails.bind(this)}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Buy Tickets
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2">
                <p>{this.state.noOfTickets}</p> //showing user input value
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectTrainsAndTickets;
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You are not setting the state properly in the showDetails method

Comment: I am new to react too. But I see this, When user inputs something in your input box you should get that data in like a onChange event and use setState to set it. then onClick of your button use this.state.noOftickets to display it. I found this amazing react tutorial scrimba.com/playlist/p7P5Hd It even has like an editor to practice.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to read up on is controlled inputs. 
https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/forms.html
There are only a few scenarios where you want to access the DOM  directly and you almost never want to do it in your constructor as you are in your example.

First initialize your state you dont even need a constructor in this case.

```
class SelectTrainsandTIckets extends Component {
    state = { ticketCount : 0, showTicketCount: false }
}
```

Since this is a controlled input you need to handle any change on that input. With events you get passed an event object where you can retrieve whatever the user is entering in your input. You want to store that change in the state variable you have setup.

```
handleChange(event){
    this.setState({ticketCount : event.target.value})
}
```

Now you need to hook this all up to your actual input element in your render() method.

```
render() {
    return(
        <input name="myInput" onChange={handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.ticketCount} />
    )
}
```

To display the current count you have already correctly displayed displayed the data but you want to hide the p element until the user clicks a button. Dont duplicate state especially for something like this. Simply hide the element until the user clicks a button.

```
<p style={this.state.showTicketCount ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}>{this.state.ticketCount}</p>
```

Finally the button to show the entered ticket count:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({showTicketCount: true})>Click me</button>
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I need to click the `button` to show the user input value...

Comment: Yes and I explained how to do that. You still need a controlled input and thats where you are having trouble. Showing or hiding an element on button click is easily searchable.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out :)

Answer (score -2):

This is what I tried with help of the answers provided here. I got the idea and I changed it to the way I wanted it to work. This is my final answer:

```
"use strict";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

class SelectTrainsAndTickets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      noOfTickets: 0,
      ticketCount: 0
    };
    this.haChange = this.haChange.bind(this);
    this.getCount = this.getCount.bind(this);
  }

  haChange(event) {
    this.setState({ noOfTickets: event.target.value });
  }
  getCount(){
      this.setState({ticketCount: this.state.noOfTickets});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2" />
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <select id="train" name="train" className="form-control">
                <option value="select" disabled="disabled">
                  - Select Train -
                </option>
                <option value="1">Train A</option>
                <option value="2">Train B</option>
                <option value="3">Train C</option>
                <option value="4">Train D</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <input onChange={this.haChange} className="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Number of tickets" />
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-2" />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2" />
            <div className="col-md-4" />
            <div className="col-md-4 text-right">

              <button onClick={this.getCount}  type="button" value={this.state.ticketCount} className="btn btn-primary">
                Buy Tickets
              </button>
              <p>{this.state.ticketCount === 0 ? '' : this.state.ticketCount}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectTrainsAndTickets;
```

Comment: This is wrong and will not work. You are not setting a value on your input. Also you should never duplicate state like that. Only store ticket count once and just hide the p element until the user clicks the button. I have updated my answer with the correct code. Please mark correct if this solves your problem.